# Save randomly generated data after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code to display an image with a description for it which is randomly generated each time a page is reloaded.

Is it possible to make the user see the same image with a description when he visits the page again?

```html
<img id='image'>
<p id='textimage'></p>
```

```js
var quotes = [{
    img: "01.png",
    quote: "text1"
  },
  {
    img: "02.png",
    quote: "text2"
  },
  {
    img: "03.png",
    quote: "text3"
  }
];

function showquote() {
  var q = quotes.length;
  var whichquote = quotes[Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1))];
  document.getElementById('textimage').innerHTML = whichquote.quote;
  document.getElementById('image').src = whichquote.img;
};
showquote();
```

Comment: Yes, but you will need to store the information the user entered somewhere and retrieve it when they next visit. To do that you could use localStorage, cookies or a server-side database with AJAX.

Comment: You need to use cookies for that (which could be deleted/cleared by the user) or need to retain user info to a database by adding account sign up functionality on your site so users can login and continue reloading the images from where they left off.

Comment: using js: cookie, localstorage, or server side: sessions, cookies, or database-based